# How to create an archive history of an SSRS report as it is run

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

A client wants to have a history and a pdf copy of the last x number of times a report has run. They want to be able to:

1) Re run the report with the same parameters (no problems with that)

2) Have a stored pdf copy of the original report for later viewing

3) Have this generically set up for all (80) reports in the system.

Does anybody know of a way that you could automatically generate and store a file copy of a report every time the user runs that report. Or alternatively a way to extract the report from the ReportServer or ReportServerTempDB databases.

I realise that SSRS has History Snapshots but as far as I can see they are of no use for my problem.

1) They have to be run as a snapshot and cannot be run directly by the user.

2) They need to have all parameters with a default value (because they are run as a snapshot via an job)

It seems odd that such a simple requirement cannot be met and I am wondering if I am missing something. Are there any third party products that supply this functionality.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: I recently found this post where they show you how to launch a stored procedure every time the report is executed. You might find it useful: http://www.advancedssrs.com/2014/01/how-can-i-run-stored-procedures-with.html

Comment: Thank you vercelli

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an archive of the report that is run, you can query the database that contains the details of all the reports that are run and the parameters that were used, who and when etc.

Look in ReportManager database. there are views that will get you part of the way there, join with the catalog to get details of the report etc.

**Note** the data is prurged on restarts (and after some time) so you need a process to copy it to another table for long term storage. i also extract the Windows users details to another table so I can have real names. This is all exposed as an SSRS report for managers.

**edit** This may not fit your requirements as when you run a report with the same parameters later you may get different results if the underlying data has changed.

Comment: Thanks Mike. It is correct that all the report details are held in the ReportsServer database and you can rerun the report with those same parameters at a later date but you will get different data. The actual report data is not stored so you cannot reproduce the report the user saw at a later point in time.  That is my problem - the users want a historical record of every report run on the system, who ran it and a copy of the actual report produced.